# sync framework WPF application

Tags: wpf, microsoft-sync-framework

I've to write code to update data in local cache used in a sync framework used in WPF a application. How to update a record in local cache based on a condition?

Comment: you mean how to synchronize to local cache using a filter?

Answer (score 0):

When you add the local cache to your WPF project it will also create either a DataSet for you.  If you want to update the data store being represented by the cache, just add something to the data set.  You can then synchronize that to the server using the SyncAgent object.